# ReferenceError: err is not defined at exports.createScreams.functions.https.onRequest

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**material that i used**

- Firebase (cloud-firestore)
- Javascript
- windows 10

**What did I do ?**

> I tried to access from local but it didn't work.

**This is an error in the console**

```
functions: ReferenceError: err is not defined
    at exports.createScreams.functions.https.onRequest (C:\Users\taiga\Github\React2\Full-stack-app\socialape-functions\functions\index.js:59:19)
    at runFunction (C:\Users\taiga\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:570:20)
    at C:\Users\taiga\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:545:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\taiga\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\taiga\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:4:12)
    at runFunction (C:\Users\taiga\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:542:12)
    at C:\Users\taiga\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:569:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>) !  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');



    admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault() });




    const firestore  = admin.firestore();
    firestore.settings({ignoreUndefinedProperties:true});


    exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     response.send("Hello world");
    });

    exports.getScreams = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

      admin.firestore().collection('screams').get()
        .then(data => {
          let screams
          data.docs.forEach(doc =>  {
            screams.push(doc.data());
          });
          return res.json(screams);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    });


    exports.createScreams = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {



      // if(req.method !== 'post') {
      //   return res.status(400).json({ error: 'method not allowed '})
      // }

       const newScreams = {
        body: req.body,
        userHandle: req.userHandle,
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
       };

       admin
       .firestore()
       .collection('screams')
       .add(newScreams)
       .then(doc => {
         res.json({Message:  `document ${doc.id} created successfully`});
       })
       .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong'});
        });
        console.error(err);
    });
```

### **Does someone know this error?**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `err` outside the catch callback:

```
       .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong'});
        });
        console.error(err);
```

You probably meant to put it inside the callback where `err` is defined:

```
       .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong'});
        });
```